# How to get the IN / OUT hour from a single column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, pivot

I have a REGISTER table in Oracle that looks like this

```
| ID | BOOOK_ID |  CLIENT_ID  |   TYPE    |          DATE           |
| 1  |   2447   |   274761    |     1     |    2020-04-07 09:38:54  | 
| 2  |   2447   |   274761    |     2     |    2020-04-07 09:39:25  |
| 3  |   2447   |   274761    |     1     |    2020-04-07 09:39:53  | 
| 4  |   2447   |   274761    |     2     |    2020-04-07 09:41:03  | 
| 5  |   1000   |   274761    |     1     |    2020-04-07 09:52:05  | 
| 6  |   2447   |   274761    |     1     |    2020-04-07 10:04:54  | 
| 7  |   1000   |   274761    |     2     |    2020-04-07 10:05:38  | 
| 8  |   2447   |   274761    |     2     |    2020-04-07 10:06:04  | 
| 9  |   3002   |   274761    |     1     |    2020-04-07 11:22:02  |
```

And the result I want is something like this

```
| ID | BOOOK_ID |            IN           |          OUT            |
| 1  |   2447   |   2020-04-07 09:38:54   |   2020-04-07 09:39:25   |
| 2  |   2447   |   2020-04-07 09:39:53   |   2020-04-07 09:41:03   |
| 3  |   1000   |   2020-04-07 09:52:05   |   2020-04-07 10:05:38   | 
| 4  |   2447   |   2020-04-07 10:04:54   |   2020-04-07 10:06:04   | 
| 5  |   3002   |   2020-04-07 11:22:02   |                         |
```

Where the type = 1 indicates a start date and type = 2 indicates an end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MATCH_RECOGNIZE**

In Oracle 12.1 and higher, you can do this easily with the `match_recognize` clause.

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';

with register (id, book_id, client_id, type_, date_) as (
  select 1, 2447, 274761, 1, to_date('2020-04-07 09:38:54') from dual union all 
  select 2, 2447, 274761, 2, to_date('2020-04-07 09:39:25') from dual union all
  select 3, 2447, 274761, 1, to_date('2020-04-07 09:39:53') from dual union all
  select 4, 2447, 274761, 2, to_date('2020-04-07 09:41:03') from dual union all
  select 5, 1000, 274761, 1, to_date('2020-04-07 09:52:05') from dual union all
  select 6, 2447, 274761, 1, to_date('2020-04-07 10:04:54') from dual union all
  select 7, 1000, 274761, 2, to_date('2020-04-07 10:05:38') from dual union all
  select 8, 2447, 274761, 2, to_date('2020-04-07 10:06:04') from dual union all
  select 9, 3002, 274761, 1, to_date('2020-04-07 11:22:02') from dual
  )
select *
from   register
match_recognize(
  partition by book_id, client_id
  order     by date_
  measures  i.date_ as date_in, o.date_ as date_out
  pattern   ( i o? )
  define    i as type_ = 1, o as type_ = 2
)
order by client_id, date_in, book_id
;

BOOK_ID CLIENT_ID DATE_IN             DATE_OUT
------- --------- ------------------- -------------------
   2447    274761 2020-04-07 09:38:54 2020-04-07 09:39:25
   2447    274761 2020-04-07 09:39:53 2020-04-07 09:41:03
   1000    274761 2020-04-07 09:52:05 2020-04-07 10:05:38
   2447    274761 2020-04-07 10:04:54 2020-04-07 10:06:04
   3002    274761 2020-04-07 11:22:02
```

A few notes: `TYPE`, `DATE`, `IN` are Oracle keywords (the last two are even **reserved** keywords), so they shouldn't be column names, either in the input or the output. I changed the first two to `TYPE_` and `DATE_` (with a trailing underscore), and I named the output columns `DATE_IN` and `DATE_OUT`. Also, I changed the `BOOOK_ID` column name to `BOOK_ID`, and you would do well to do the same; the English word book has only two o's, not three.

Then - if you try this in SQL Developer, you will find that the question mark in the `PATTERN` clause of `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` throws an error. This is a defect in SQL Developer; if you run the same query in SQL*Plus or other interfaces, it will work just fine. In SQL Developer, you will need to change `o?` to the equivalent expression `o{0,1}`.

= = = =

**PIVOT**

In Oracle 11.1 and higher, you can do this with the `PIVOT` operator. You need some prep work (the subquery) to match the "in" and "out" event into pairs; the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()`, partitioned by book, client **and type**, is a simple way to do that.

```
select client_id, book_id, date_in, date_out
from   ( select client_id, book_id, type_, date_, 
                row_number() over (partition by book_id, client_id, type_ 
                                   order by date_) as rn 
         from   register r
       )
pivot  (max(date_) for type_ in (1 as date_in, 2 as date_out))
order  by client_id, book_id, date_in
;
```

Comment: Your answer is really awesome and as Gordon's answer they both return what I expected, however I'm getting problem because I need to make a INNER JOIN with another table and I realized that it's not possible with match_recognize. Is there a way to accomplish the same result without using match_recognize or a way to join this result with an another table?

Comment: @Luigi777 - "it's not possible with match recognize" is not true, what gave you that idea? Other than that, you need to explain exactly what kind of join you need to make - there's nothing about it in your original question. And indeed, perhaps that merits its own, different question (start a new thread, linking to this one if it helps). In any case, if you need a join before the `match_recognize` thing, it can be done in a subquery. If you need to join the results to something else, then the whole `match_recognize` can be a subquery, then join to whatever.

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions.  If we assume the types are correctly interleaved as in your sample data:

```
select rownum as id, book_id, client_id, date as in_date, out_date
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by book_id, client_id order by date) as out_date
      from t
     ) t
where type = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=31318abd6d9798f39fde4cd31d2a01a0) is a db<>fiddle.

If the data is not correctly interleaved, you should ask a *new* question with good examples of what can go wrong and what you want the final result to look like.  This answers the question that you have asked here.